How to reveal an element based off animation?
I have an animation that extends down and then to the right to display a grid of images. Given that the .addEventListener("click") changes the display to grid, it reveals the content immediately. I want to resolve this in one of two ways:

Wait for the display: "grid" change to fade-in when the border animation is complete
As the border grows in size to the right, the pre-populated images are revealed.

Hopefully this quick graphic adds some context:

Here is what I have so far for code


const showButton = document.getElementById("option-button");
const optionsGrid = document.getElementById("option-grid");
const optionRadios = document.getElementsByClassName("option-radio");
const optionOne = document.getElementById("1");
const optionTwo = document.getElementById("2");
const optionThree = document.getElementById("3");
const optionFour = document.getElementById("4");
const optionOneImage = document.getElementById("option-1-image").src;
const optionTwoImage = document.getElementById("option-2-image").src;
const optionThreeImage = document.getElementById("option-3-image").src;
const optionFourImage = document.getElementById("option-4-image").src;

showButton.addEventListener("click", showOptions);
function showOptions() {
  let array = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
    array.push(optionRadios[i].classList.value);
  }
  
  if (array.includes("option-radio hide")) {
    optionsGrid.style.animation = "open-animation 500ms linear 1";
      optionsGrid.style.display = "grid";
    for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
    optionRadios[i].classList.replace("hide", "active");
   }
  } else {
    optionsGrid.style.display = "none";
    for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
    optionRadios[i].classList.replace("active", "hide");
   }
  } 
}

optionOne.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showButton.style.backgroundImage = `url("${optionOneImage}")`;
  showButton.innerHTML = "";
  
  optionsGrid.style.display = "none";
  for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
    optionRadios[i].classList.replace("active", "hide");
   }
});

optionTwo.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showButton.style.backgroundImage = `url("${optionTwoImage}")`;
  showButton.innerHTML = "";
  
  optionsGrid.style.display = "none";
  for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
    optionRadios[i].classList.replace("active", "hide");
   }
});

optionThree.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showButton.style.backgroundImage = `url("${optionThreeImage}")`;
  showButton.innerHTML = "";
  
  optionsGrid.style.display = "none";
  for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
    optionRadios[i].classList.replace("active", "hide");
   }
});

optionFour.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showButton.style.backgroundImage = `url("${optionFourImage}")`;
  showButton.innerHTML = "";
  
  optionsGrid.style.display = "none";
  for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
    optionRadios[i].classList.replace("active", "hide");
   }
});
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

#option-button {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
}

#option-grid {
  display: none;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: 1250px;
  height: 450px;
  place-items: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes open-animation {
  0% {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
  }
  50% {
    height: 450px;
    width: 10px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 1250px;
  }
}
<fieldset id="console-select">
  <legend>Radio Option</legend>
  <button type="button" id="option-button">Select</button>
  <div id="option-grid">
    <div class="option-radio hide">
      <label for="1">
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="1" id="1" hidden>
        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x200" id="option-1-image">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="option-radio hide">
      <label for="2">
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="2" id="2" hidden>
        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x199" id="option-2-image">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="option-radio hide">
      <label for="3">
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="3" id="3" hidden>
        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x198" id="option-3-image">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="option-radio hide">
      <label for="4">
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="4" id="4" hidden>
        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x197" id="option-4-image">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>



Here is a link to the CodePen
Thank you for any help!

Use the animationend event to call a function after the animation is completed.

One somewhat simple fix (option 2), would be to add overflow: hidden
Could also add margin: 0 13px to the cells to prevent the shift after the animation finishes.


const showButton = document.getElementById("option-button");
const optionsGrid = document.getElementById("option-grid");
const optionRadios = document.getElementsByClassName("option-radio");
const optionOne = document.getElementById("1");
const optionTwo = document.getElementById("2");
const optionThree = document.getElementById("3");
const optionFour = document.getElementById("4");
const optionOneImage = document.getElementById("option-1-image").src;
const optionTwoImage = document.getElementById("option-2-image").src;
const optionThreeImage = document.getElementById("option-3-image").src;
const optionFourImage = document.getElementById("option-4-image").src;

showButton.addEventListener("click", showOptions);
function showOptions() {
  let array = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
    array.push(optionRadios[i].classList.value);
  }
  
  if (array.includes("option-radio hide")) {
    optionsGrid.style.animation = "open-animation 500ms linear 1";
      optionsGrid.style.display = "grid";
    for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
    optionRadios[i].classList.replace("hide", "active");
   }
  } else {
    optionsGrid.style.display = "none";
    for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
    optionRadios[i].classList.replace("active", "hide");
   }
  } 
}

optionOne.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showButton.style.backgroundImage = `url("${optionOneImage}")`;
  showButton.innerHTML = "";
  
  optionsGrid.style.display = "none";
  for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
    optionRadios[i].classList.replace("active", "hide");
   }
});

optionTwo.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showButton.style.backgroundImage = `url("${optionTwoImage}")`;
  showButton.innerHTML = "";
  
  optionsGrid.style.display = "none";
  for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
    optionRadios[i].classList.replace("active", "hide");
   }
});

optionThree.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showButton.style.backgroundImage = `url("${optionThreeImage}")`;
  showButton.innerHTML = "";
  
  optionsGrid.style.display = "none";
  for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
    optionRadios[i].classList.replace("active", "hide");
   }
});

optionFour.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showButton.style.backgroundImage = `url("${optionFourImage}")`;
  showButton.innerHTML = "";
  
  optionsGrid.style.display = "none";
  for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
    optionRadios[i].classList.replace("active", "hide");
   }
});
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 13px;
}

#option-button {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
}

#option-grid {
  display: none;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: 1250px;
  height: 450px;
  place-items: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes open-animation {
  0% {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
  }
  50% {
    height: 450px;
    width: 10px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 1250px;
  }
}
<fieldset id="console-select">
  <legend>Radio Option</legend>
  <button type="button" id="option-button">Select</button>
  <div id="option-grid">
    <div class="option-radio hide">
      <label for="1">
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="1" id="1" hidden>
        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x200" id="option-1-image">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="option-radio hide">
      <label for="2">
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="2" id="2" hidden>
        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x199" id="option-2-image">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="option-radio hide">
      <label for="3">
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="3" id="3" hidden>
        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x198" id="option-3-image">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="option-radio hide">
      <label for="4">
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="4" id="4" hidden>
        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x197" id="option-4-image">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>




The overflow: hidden was a great solution! That achieved option 2. However, at the beginning of the animation, the content is pushed to the left and then gets the correct positioning after the animation is complete. Is there any way to avoid this?

Can add something like margin: 0 13px to the cells to prevent the shifting
